# WPF, property in ValidationRule never set

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind a property in my `DataContext` to a property in a `ValidationRule`:

```
public class ReleaseValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    // I want to bind a value from my DataContext to this property:
    public CheckboxViewModels ValidReleases { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Based on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/982e2fcf-780f-4f1c-9730-cedcd4e24320/), I created the `CheckboxViewModels` class just to act as a wrapper for a `List<CheckboxViewModel>` so that the list could be a `DependencyProperty` so that I could bind to it.  However, in my `Validate` method on my `ValidationRule`, the `ValidReleases` list is always empty.  Here's my XAML:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Release" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ReleaseValidationRule>
                    <local:ReleaseValidationRule.ValidReleases>
                        <local:CheckboxViewModels List="{Binding Path=Releases,
                            Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"/>
                    </local:ReleaseValidationRule.ValidReleases>
                </local:ReleaseValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I know the `Releases` property (what I'm binding to the `List` property of `CheckboxViewModels`) has content because I have a `TreeView` just above the `TextBox` that shows the contents of `Releases`.  The converter I have on the `CheckboxViewModels.List` binding does nothing, it's just a place where I can set a breakpoint.  The funny thing is, that converter breakpoint never gets hit.  It's as if the whole line `<local:CheckboxViewModels List="{Binding Path=Releases, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"/>` never gets executed, so the `ValidReleases` property in my `ValidationRule` never gets set.  What's going on?

**Edit:**  here's what `CheckboxViewModels` looks like:

```
public class CheckboxViewModels : DependencyObject, IList<CheckboxViewModel>,
    IEnumerable<CheckboxViewModel>
{
    ...members necessary to implement IList, IEnumerable...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "List",
            typeof(List<CheckboxViewModel>),
            typeof(CheckboxViewModels),
            new PropertyMetadata(new List<CheckboxViewModel>())
        );

    public List<CheckboxViewModel> List
    {
        get { return (List<CheckboxViewModel>)GetValue(ListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using validation rules and instead followed [this tutorial about implementing `IDataErrorInfo`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx).  That was my class instance is fully initialized by the time I get into `this[string]` to figure out the error message.  The data I had been trying to pass in was just data from another property on the same instance.  That is, I wanted to validate `Property1` using some data from `Property2`.  With `IDataErrorInfo`, when I'm validating `Property1` and assembling an error message if necessary, I have access to `Property2` as desired, without having to pass anything in.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a missing Property Changed notification somewhere. Hard to see what CheckboxModels is about from this, but if it were ObservableCollection you'd get property changed without any extra work. Does this make sense?

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: I updated my question to include `CheckboxViewModels` code.  I'm not sure what events I should hook up.

Comment: I do not see a requirement here for making the list a DP, since it looks like the binding Source and not the target. I would add a new property, for now, of ObservableCollection<CheckBoxViewModel> and try and re-work the solution with it. You can call it something clever like Releases_NEW and post any bindings that are giving you trouble. If it becomes clear that a DP is necessary, I see an avenue to try and make it work, and you will still have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I just feel silly.  I had had a constructor in `CheckboxViewModels` that set `List = new List<CheckboxViewModel>()`.  I think this was somehow resetting something?  I removed that constructor and the initial value of `List` is set only in the `Register` method for the `DependencyProperty`:  `new PropertyMetadata(new List<CheckboxViewModel>())`.  `ValidReleases` is now populated as expected with the following XAML:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Release" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ReleaseValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                    <local:ReleaseValidationRule.ValidReleases>
                        <local:CheckboxViewModels
                            List="{Binding Path=Releases, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </local:ReleaseValidationRule.ValidReleases>
                </local:ReleaseValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**Edit:**  not so silly afterall:  not having a constructor in `CheckboxViewModels` resulted in two dependency properties of type `CheckboxViewModels` using the same list, so I had releases and other data in both the `Releases` property and another property.  Adding the constructor back to `CheckboxViewModels` results in `ValidReleases` not having any items again.  I think I must be binding something incorrectly.